# Android : Get current date and time from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I am developing a simple game where users get daily bonus.I want to get current date and time from firebase server as i don't want to rely on device time which could be manipulated.
I went through ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in firebase but don't know how to use it.It returns a map with value as timestamp.How can i convert that timestamp into date.I want to get Today's date from firebase when ever user clicks on daily bonus.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since Firebase Introduced [Callable Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), you can easily use it in your app by creating a Callable Function in Firebase Cloud Functions.
in your `index.js`, create a Function and make it return the current timestamp

```
exports.getTime = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
return Date.now()
})
```

then deploy it to Firebase Cloud Functions

then in your Android App add the Callable Functions dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0'
```

then call the function from your app like this, and make sure you are typing the same name of the function '**getTime**' as in your Cloud Function

```
    FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable("getTime")
            .call().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(HttpsCallableResult httpsCallableResult) {
            long timestamp = (long) httpsCallableResult.getData();

        }
    });
```

you can also make a Simple interface if you want to call this method in multiple classes

```
public interface OnGetServerTime {
    void onSuccess(long timestamp);

    void onFailed();
}

 public void getServerTime(final OnGetServerTime onComplete) {
    FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable("getTime")
            .call()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        long timestamp = (long) task.getResult().getData();
                        if (onComplete != null) {
                            onComplete.onSuccess(timestamp);
                        }
                    } else {
                        onComplete.onFailed();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you.

Comment: That's nice idea, but I would like to know timezone in which date/time is returned

Answer (score 1):

`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is just a token that Firebase Realtime Database converts to a number on the server when it's used as a child value during write operation.  The date only appears in the database after the write completes.

If you want that value, you can read it back out of the database at the location you wrote it.  But you should understand that this requires two round trips with the database, first to write it, then again to read it.  By the time you get the value back, it will no longer be a perfect representation of the current moment in time, as it represents the moment in time that the value was initially written.

Comment: this means i can't use firebase timestamp to get current date and time daily  to give daily bonus...

Comment: It'll be off by a few seconds. If you want to do it via the REST api, post {".sv":"timestamp"}  this is the equivalent json version of the token that you said :)

Comment: @Doug, so is there any way of getting the date and time using firebase without read-write approach? Here is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410208/flutter-firebase-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-to-datetime-object), can you please help?

Answer (score -8):

you can convert timestamp to date and time using java.util.Date. 
for example

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
```

Comment: The actual value of `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` doesn't work that way.

Comment: Have you checked what is is the datatype of ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. ServerValue.TIMESTAMP needs to be converted in long

Comment: ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is a Map.  It doesn't have a getTime() method.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue.html#TIMESTAMP