# Flutter: Firebase FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to DateTime object

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have

```
FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

I couldn't find a way to convert this timestamp to `DateTime` object in Flutter. Is there any way to do it? Or any other API call using firebase?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is not a timestamp, but a so-called sentinel - a marker that gets sent to the server, that the server then recognizes and interprets to write the current timestamp. That means there is no way to convert `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to a timestamp on the client.

What you can do is *write* `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to a document on the server, and observe the value that is written to that document. This value will be a valid timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Puf, can you also suggest a free API for this kind of work? Can [Google NTP](https://developers.google.com/time/) be used, I can't figure it out yet. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have no recommendations there (they'd also be off topic for Stack Overflow). Any time server that works for your purposes is fine I guess.

Answer (score 5):

If you have as `serverTimeStamp` field in your document you can convert it to `DateTime` as follows;

```
final DateTime dateTimeFromServerTimeStamp =
 (documentSnapshot.data()['serverTimeStamp'] as Timestamp).toDate();
```

Comment: And if you already KNOW that it is a Timestamp, I find that you don't even have to write `as Timestamp`. Just put `toDate()` after it and it will work. Your IDE won't know that it will work until at runtime, and thus won't autocomplete it for you, but it will work nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used serverTimeStamp in firebase, and you're reading it back you can read the timestamp read from firebase using DateTime.parse() :

```dart
DateTime timestamp = DateTime.parse( json['ts'].toString() );
```

Comment: Seems to do exactly the same as adding `.toDate()` after the downloaded Timestamp variable... only more complicated! :p

Comment: well you learn about new functions everyday !

Comment: Isn't that so...! 

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works in **my case** as a workaround. I am using json_annotation, json_serilaizable, build_runner.

These are the libraries version:

json_serializable: ^5.0.2

build_runner: ^2.1.2

json_annotation: ^4.1.0

```
part 'podcast_comment_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class CommentModel extends BaseModel {
  final String? id;
  final String podcastId;
  final String? comment;

  @JsonKey(
    fromJson: ServerTimestampConverter.fromJson,
    toJson: ServerTimestampConverter.toJson,
  )
  Object? dueDate;
  final CreatorModel? creator;

  CommentModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.podcastId,
    this.comment,
    this.creator,
    this.dueDate,
  });

  factory CommentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _$CommentModelFromJson(json);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CommentModelToJson(this);

  @override
  CommentEntity toEntity() {
    return CommentEntity(
      id: this.id,
      podcastId: this.podcastId,
      dueDate: ServerTimestampConverter.fromJson(this.dueDate),
      creator: this.creator?.toEntity(),
      comment: this.comment,
    );
  }
}

class ServerTimestampConverter {
  static DateTime? fromJson(Object? json) {
   if (json is Timestamp) {
        return json.toDate();
  }
    return null;
}

  static Object? toJson(Object? fieldValue) {
    print('toJson is FieldValue fireStore object $fieldValue');
    return fieldValue as FieldValue;
  }
}
```

**I hope it's useful.**