# Flutter chat app saves a message timestamp from a device time

Tags: flutter, dart, timestamp

I have a problem with creating same timestamp in messages that users deliver to each other.

This is a function to send a message:

```
  void onSendMessage(String content, int type) {
    if (content.trim() != '') {
      textEditingController.clear();

      var documentReference = Firestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .document(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId)
          .document(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());

      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        await transaction.set(
          documentReference,
          {
            'idFrom': id,
            'idTo': peerId,
            'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
            'content': content,
            'type': type
          },
        );
      });

      cacheSet(groupChatId, content, peerNickname, peerAvatar);
      listScrollController.animateTo(0.0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Nothing to send');
    }
  }
```

However this `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()` creates timestamp based on user's device. This means if userA sends a message ("hello") to userB at 10:00 but if userB replies ("world") and his device time is 9:50 it will be shown before userA's message which is false.

Something like this:

```
09:50 userB - "world"
10:00 userA - "hello"
```

Is there a general time format regardless of device time? Is it possible to set without using external API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had this problem before i changed my code to **FieldValue.serverTimestamp()**.

> Change **DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()** to **FieldValue.serverTimestamp()**.

So try this:

```
 {
        'idFrom': id,
        'idTo': peerId,
        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        'content': content,
        'type': type
  },
```

Check those: [FieldValue Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue) , [Flutter: Firebase FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410208/flutter-firebase-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-to-datetime-object).

Comment: But when I try to create a document I get `Instance of 'FieldValue'`

Comment: Hi, Did you checked the links i provided ?

Comment: Because it's not a String, document() takes a string as parameter to use it as a document name. and why are you using transaction if i may ask ?

Comment: Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).