# Error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am setting the current date in firebase and trying to retrieve it to use as a reference. But somehow the results vary. Sometimes I'm having a null value but sometimes it's okay. I tried to add a delay command but it is still behaving the same. Please help. Thanks!

```
        //set current date
        await db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid).set({
          'currDate': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        }, SetOptions(merge: true));

        DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot =
            await db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid).get();

        Timestamp currDate = documentSnapshot.data()!['currDate'];
```

Edit: I'm not really sure if it is connected but I have 2 methods that call the same logic. One is under a HookWidget which almost always fail and another in StatefulWidget which never have a problem.

Edit: I don't really know why. But when I move the event which update the current date to a Stateful Widget, it is now working. Hopefully someone can clarify this.

Comment: This should help you understand why this is happening - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627037/13840864

Comment: Thanks, I will check on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

`db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid).get().then((value) => value.data()!['currDate']);`

You can also try to chain then with `db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid).set` if still not working

Comment: I don't actually understand what the first syntax that you show. But I have tried this. `        DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot = await db
            .collection(Paths.playersPath)
            .doc(uid)
            .get()
            .then((value) => value.data()!['currDate']);` and still not working

Comment: 1) unless you are using documentSnapshot somewhere else you could get rid of 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot = await' part if you are using .then it is redundant
2) could you debug line by line to see where exactly problem lies? You could check if your db is updated every time with correct Timestamp and then if you are able to retrieve it correctly

Comment: I will still need it. I just show a minimal code just to show my issue. Ok, I will try to check. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, let me know if you need any more help :)