# How to add server timestamp to firestore document in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am new to firestore. When I try to add a document through the add method within the function addSubject, it throws the error "Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'FieldValue'". I am getting a similar error when I am setting the field to DateTime.now(). How to add the server timestamp to the document?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<bool> addSubject(FirebaseFirestore x, FirebaseAuth auth, String subjectName) async{
  try {
    var doc = { "subject": subjectName };
    await x.collection('subjects').add(appendCreateAudit(doc, auth));
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

Map<String, dynamic> appendCreateAudit(Map<String, dynamic> x, FirebaseAuth auth) {
  x["createdAt"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  x["createdBy"] = auth.currentUser!;
  x["updatedAt"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  x["updatedBy"] = auth.currentUser!;
  print(x);
  return x;
}

Map<String, dynamic> appendUpdateAudit(Map<String, dynamic> x, FirebaseAuth auth) {
  x["updatedBy"] = auth.currentUser!;
  x["updatedAt"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  return x;
}
```

It is possible to send the time stamp as a string, but that is not an optimal solution.

1. Is there any way one can store timestamp variable in firestore, without first converting it to string?
2. I am trying to instruct the server to put a timestamp on the field by passing on FieldValue.serverTimestamp(). Can it be done through flutter?

Reference question
[Flutter: Firebase FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to DateTime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410208/flutter-firebase-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-to-datetime-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was being thrown by this line

```
x["createdAt"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Reason: I declared doc as a var

```
var doc = { "subject": subjectName };
```

Dart was interpreting doc as Map<String, String > instead of Map <String, dynamic>, hence the error.

Fix:
Map<String, dynamic> doc = { "subject": subjectName };
Working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The value that you are sending is not of the type `String`. Simply convert it woth `toString()` before sending and it will fix the error.

Example:

```
 FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toString();
```

or just:

```
 "${FieldValue.serverTimestamp()}";
```

Comment: When using FieldValue.serverTimestamp(); it did not show any error. 
But the value saved in the field is "FieldValue(Instance of 'FieldValueWeb')" instead of the timestamp.

Comment: what does FieldValue.serverTimestamp() have as a return type? try to get the actual value out of it and than convert it into a string if it isn't so. (probably you have added  "${FieldValue.serverTimestamp()}" so it might return that is an Instance of 'FieldValueWeb').

Comment: "The FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is not a timestamp, but a so-called sentinel - a marker that gets sent to the server, that the server then recognizes and interprets to write the current timestamp."
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410208/flutter-firebase-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-to-datetime-object

Comment: all right than simply do: final DateTime dateTimeFromServerTimeStamp =
 (documentSnapshot.data()['serverTimeStamp'] as Timestamp).toDate(); to convert your serverTimestamp to a Date type and than pass that value as a string like so  x["updatedAt"] = '$dateTimeFromServerTimeStamp'; In simple you are converting your FieldValue.serverTimestamp() into a Date type and than passing that date as a string into the request parameter;

Comment: That is one way, but a complex way to achieve it. Also, it would necessarily store the time as a string in the firestore database. 
1) Is there any way one can store timestamp variable in firestore, without first converting it to string?
2) I am trying to instruct the server to put a timestamp on the field by passing on FieldValue.serverTimestamp(). Can it be done through flutter?