# Get firebase/firestore SERVERTIME and convert to date (month and day)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the server time either from Firebase or Firestore. I have tried `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` but it is not pulling a value when i try to view in `Log.d("Time", "${SERVERValue.TIMESTAMP}")`.

What i would like to do is eventually convert this to a simple date i.e. month and day so that i can store the future expiry date of an account. e.g. take today's date, add 31 days and in the future once the date is reached lock the user out of the account if not renewed.

How would I retrieve the original stored date, convert to date and then do a logical check to see if expired or not?

Comment: Unless you are trying to write the server timestamp to the database, using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is not the easiest approach. Instead consider creating a minimal Cloud Function that returns the time, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865034/android-get-current-date-and-time-from-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, i am reading through that link, but silly question, where do i find the index.js. its the first time i am trying out cloud functions

Comment: `index.js` is a file you create, that contains the code for your Cloud Functions. If you're new to Cloud Functions, I recommend reading the [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), taking the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/), and one of the many [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=Firebase+cloud+functions+tutorial) out there.

Comment: great, will have a look

Answer (score 2):

`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a constant that is used as a placeholder value that once uploaded to the server, is replaced with the server time.

Based on the sensitivity of setting an account's expiry date, I would not handle this on your client and instead use one of the Admin SDKs on a trusted server or use Cloud Functions.

However, to get the current server time, you can make use of [Kronos](https://github.com/lyft/Kronos-Android) and the `time.google.com` NTP server (You can also use `time1`, `time2`, `time3` and `time4` appended with `.google.com`).

Comment: the idea is to write the value to the database to a field called "account". this will ideally be the expiry date, otherwise it would be the data at the time of writing and then in future always do a logical check if the date written is pass 31 days (predefined range) as an example.